# Mono (or MvvmCross) Equivalent to CollectionViewSource

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is there an equivalent to `CollectionViewSource` in Windows Phone / WinRT on other Mono platforms - MonoDroid/MonoTouch or utilizing the MvvmCross library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx then no, not directly.

Each platform has direct collection sources (like MvxAdapter and MvxTableViewSource) and it's trivial to write filtering/sorting (and less trivial grouping) into your view model so that it works with the views. However no-one has yet (that I know of) written a reusable filtering/sorting/grouping layer on top of this.

Comment: Will improve this answer later with code. Sorry on phone keyboard only right now.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your response :) In that case I can just write a wrapper similar to CollectionViewSource to use in the view models

Comment: I've added an early version of my implementation to a gist here: https://gist.github.com/jamie94bc/6262479

Comment: (Nowhere near as complete as MSFT's solution)